# iOS CPU% stays high after image save

Tags: iphone, memory, ios4, cpu, cpu-usage

I have an app that shows thumbnails of images that I save to app, then the user taps on a thumbnail they see a full size image that they can flick through (similar to the photos app)

My issue, that I noticed is that when I add images from a UIImagePicker, then tap on a thumbnail again, the CPU jumps up to 140-150% (or higher) and stays there.

I am able to replicate this every time only when I save a new image to the documents directory via the picker.

I was using the Activity Monitor to view the CPU%.  I am curious if anyone else ever had a similar situation, or have any ideas as to what can cause this.  This can possibly just my misinterpretation of the Activity Monitor Instrument.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Decoding images is probably a computation intensive task, depending on the resolution. What do you mean utilization stays at 100%, it never goes down? ever?

Comment: I was just testing again.  Here were my steps. (Happens even with one or two images)  I choose one from the Image picker, save it to the documents directory, then when I choose the thumbnail and go to the ScrollView, the CPU utilization spikes up 180+ and stays there until I close the app down.  If I do not save any images, the CPU only slightly goes up, and then goes back down to 0, the moment I add an image, it just stays up very high.

Comment: On a side note, the reason I am seeing more than 100% CPU usage, is because I was profiling on an iPad 2 (dual cores). I tested on a 3Gs, and it peaks up to 80+%, it is really weird as it only does this after I add an image.

Comment: Ok, another update.  In my save image process, I was calling my save image method using NSInvocationOperation.  I removed that, and saved the image by just calling my method directly, and it does not keep the CPU usage high (it actually goes back down to 0% after save)  Now I just need to figure out why that is :-)

Comment: As always, Instruments is your best tool for figuring out performance issues like this.  In particular, I'd use Time Profiler against your running application to see where it's spending the most time.  Charge methods and libraries that you don't recognize to their callers (by right-clicking on them) and it should be clear what the culprit is here.  You can also narrow the time range in Instruments to look first at what goes on during your initial image picking, and then what follows.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  Yup, I have been using instruments quite a bit.  I love them.  I will try Time profiler.  I will say this however, after I removed the NSInvocationOperation, my performance has increased dramatically.  This may have been a case where I was trying to do a little to much :-)  The CPU goes up only a little now, and drops right back down to 0. When it was peaking, it was also producing Memory warnings, which I am no longer getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, it was the NSInvocationOperation I was using to save my images.  The moment I removed that, my performance on all devices drastically improved.

I do not know why this is the case however, but removing it helped.  Thank you all for your comments.  It was chasing down this issue for a while, to the point where I was certain it was a memory issue.  I must read more on the NSInvocationOperation to understand what my underlying issue was.